# Return list of all files in a directory trouble

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm still in an introductory course in python. i'm trying to write a  program that returns a list of all the file names in a directory using recursions but for some reason it is not working as expected. here is my code:  Thank you

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path('/Users/name/Documents/')

def directory_files (dirct: Path) -> list:
    Lf = []
    if dirct.is_file:
        Lf.append(dirct)
    else:
        for d in list(dirct.iterdir()):
            directory_files(d)

    return Lf
```

Comment: @erip: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/

Comment: where should I put return directory_files(d) ?

Comment: the thing here is that you forgot to save the result of your recursive call, also `is_file` is a function so you have to call it to know if it is or not a file.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to call `is_file`, if you want to fill your list with files you need to check if `dirct` is a directory, not being a file does not make it  a directory. You can also simply extend your list recursing on each element:

```
def directory_files(dirct: Path) -> list:
    Lf = []
    if dirct.is_dir():
        for d in dirct.iterdir():
            Lf.extend(directory_files(d))
    else:
        Lf.append(dirct)   
    return Lf
```

Demo:

```
In [6]: ls
bar.txt  foo.txt  test2/

In [7]: p = Path(".")

In [8]: directory_files(p)
Out[8]: 
[PosixPath('foo.txt'),
 PosixPath('bar.txt'),
 PosixPath('test2/bar2.txt'),
 PosixPath('test2/foo2.txt')]
```

If you want just the names use the .name attribute:

```
def directory_files (dirct: Path) -> list:
    Lf = []
    if dirct.is_dir():
        for d in dirct.iterdir():
            Lf.extend(directory_files(d))
    else:
        Lf.append(dirct.name)
    return Lf
```

Demo:

```
In [10]: directory_files(p)
Out[10]: ['foo.txt', 'bar.txt', 'bar2.txt', 'foo2.txt']
```

`is_file` like `is_dir` are methods which need to be called, `if dirct.is_file` is checking if `dirct.is_file` which is a reference to a method is `True` which is always the case, the parens `is_file()` actually call the method which then returns a boolean.

If you want to explicitly check for file you also need to add an `is_file`, for instance a named pipe is not a directory but would not pass an `is_file` test so:

```
def directory_files(dirct: Path) -> list:
    Lf = []
    if dirct.is_dir():
        for d in dirct.iterdir():
            Lf.extend(directory_files(d))
    elif dirct.is_file():
        Lf.append(dirct.name)
    return Lf
```

You can see the difference in the output:

```
In [27]: ls
bar.txt  foo_pipe|  foo.txt  test2/

In [28]: p = Path(".")

In [29]: directory_files1(p)  # has if dirct.is_file()
Out[29]: 
[PosixPath('foo.txt'),
 PosixPath('bar.txt'),
 PosixPath('test2/bar2.txt'),
 PosixPath('test2/foo2.txt')]

In [30]: directory_files(p)
Out[30]: 
[PosixPath('foo.txt'),
 PosixPath('bar.txt'),
 PosixPath('test2/bar2.txt'),
 PosixPath('test2/foo2.txt'),
 PosixPath('foo_pipe')]
```

You may find [rcviz](https://github.com/carlsborg/rcviz) a nice tool to help your understanding of recursion, it can create a graph where:

*The edges are numbered by the order in which they were traversed by the execution. 2. The edges are colored from black to grey to indicate order of traversal : black edges first, grey edges last.*

[image]

It is a bit hard to see here but if you click on the image it should make it a lot easier to see.

Comment: You recommend using `isfile`, then don't use it.

Comment: @erip: He did not recommend to use `is_file`, he said the problem was that it wasn't called.

Comment: ...and it still isn't in this code. `isfile` is in `os`, which OP isn't using, by the way. You're searching for `is_file`.

Comment: Agreed. Downvoting because your answer to OP's question was wrong, on the other hand, is not. OP didn't "forget to call `isfile`"; OP forgot to call `is_file()`. You then proceed to give a solution that is completely different from OP's original code without telling him why he should use your way instead.

Comment: @erip, the OP did forget to actually call the method so again not sure what you are talking about

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: He's being needlessly pedantic because you wrote `isfile` is your answer instead of `is_file`.

Comment: Pedantic because these are important distinctions... If OP was using `sklearn`, I wouldn't post an answer with `shogun` examples. I didn't know a downvote would make someone quite so pissy.

Comment: Thank you all for your input, I'm sorry I just learnt about recursions yesterday

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thank you so much for taking the time to write your answer, it was very thorough and understandable

Comment: @KareemAmrSr.AbouGhazala, no worries, I added a link to a nice lib that creates visual representations of the recursive calls, it should help you get an understanding of what is happening